# Invoking IKImageEditPanel for IKImageView without doubleClick is very slow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to Invoke the `IKImageEditPanel` without a double Click in `IKImageView`. So I Invoked like this.

```
- (IBAction)imageProperties:(id)sender  { 
    IKImageEditPanel *editor = [IKImageEditPanel sharedImageEditPanel];
    [editor setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(400,200)];
    [editor setDataSource:self]; // I have set the DataSource.
    [editor makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

And this is my DataSource methods..

```
- (CGImageRef)image {   
    return imageView.image;    // imageView is my IKImageView
}


- (void)setImage: (CGImageRef)image imageProperties: (NSDictionary *)metaData {
    [imageView setImage:image imageProperties:metaData];
}
```

This working correctly but it is very slow when compared to the default `IKImageEditPanel` (Invoked using double Click). What is the correct way to access the `IKImageEditPanel` ?

Comment: @w.m I answered my own question. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the DataSource methods and Invoke the `IKImageEditPanel` with this method.

```
- (IBAction)editPanel:(id)sender {
    IKImageEditPanel *editor = [IKImageEditPanel sharedImageEditPanel];
    [editor setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(400,200)];
    [editor setDataSource:imageView]; // Here imageView is your IKImageView.
    [editor makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

I don't how this working, but it is. This got approved in the Appstore, too. So you can use this method.